# lwjgl slick util text drawing not working

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm having trouble drawing text with legacy LWJGL. There seems to be no problem, but there is no text displayed on the screen. How do I fix it? Code here.
constructor:

```
public Text(Canvas canvas, int x, int y, String text) {
        super(canvas, x, y);
        this.text = text;
        Font awtFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24); //name, style (PLAIN, BOLD, or ITALIC), size
        font = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, false); //base Font, anti-aliasing true/false
    }
```

and rendering:

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
font.drawString(x, y, text);
GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
```

I googled it, but things like GL_BLEND didn't work.

Comment: please correct the format of the code. I suggest to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What's the error with that? Did you get any error message? Maybe an screenshot of how it looks like and what you expect? Not sure if that code is enough to understand the problem. Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: no error message

Comment: with that level of info is hard to suggest something. please edit your post and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).